Android14’s native settings show different options than those in the layout file
I'd like to block some of the options in the native settings, but the actual display is different from the one in the layout file.
The following is code from the "apps.xml" layout file:
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:settings="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:key="apps_screen"
    android:title="@string/apps_dashboard_title">

    <Preference
        android:key="all_app_infos"
        android:title="@string/all_apps"
        android:summary="@string/summary_placeholder"
        android:order="-999"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.applications.manageapplications.ManageApplications"
        settings:keywords="@string/keywords_applications_settings"/>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="recent_apps_category"
        android:title="@string/recent_app_category_title"
        android:order="-998"
        settings:searchable="false">
        <!-- Placeholder for a list of recent apps -->

        <!-- See all apps -->
        <Preference
            android:key="see_all_apps"
            android:title="@string/default_see_all_apps_title"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_24dp"
            android:fragment="com.android.settings.applications.manageapplications.ManageApplications"
            android:order="5"
            settings:searchable="false">
        </Preference>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="general_category"
        android:title="@string/category_name_general"
        android:order="-997"
        android:visibility="gone"
        settings:searchable="false"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="default_apps"
        android:title="@string/app_default_dashboard_title"
        android:order="-996"
        settings:controller="com.android.settings.applications.DefaultAppsPreferenceController">
        <intent android:action="android.settings.MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS"/>
    </Preference>

    <Preference
        android:key="cloned_apps"
        android:title="@string/cloned_apps_dashboard_title"
        android:summary="@string/summary_placeholder"
        android:order="-995"
        settings:controller="com.android.settings.applications.ClonedAppsPreferenceController"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.applications.manageapplications.ManageApplications">
        <extra
            android:name="classname"
            android:value="com.android.settings.Settings$ClonedAppsListActivity"/>
        <intent android:action="android.settings.MANAGE_CLONED_APPS_SETTINGS"/>
    </Preference>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="dashboard_tile_placeholder"
        android:order="10"/>

    <Preference
        android:key="hibernated_apps"
        android:title="@string/unused_apps"
        android:summary="@string/summary_placeholder"
        android:order="15"
        settings:keywords="app_hibernation_key"
        settings:controller="com.android.settings.applications.HibernatedAppsPreferenceController">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.MANAGE_UNUSED_APPS"/>
    </Preference>

    <!--<Preference
        android:key="app_battery_usage"
        android:order="17"
        android:title="@string/app_battery_usage_title"
        android:summary="@string/app_battery_usage_summary"
        settings:controller="com.android.settings.applications.AppBatteryUsagePreferenceController"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.applications.manageapplications.ManageApplications">
        <extra
            android:name="classname"
            android:value="com.android.settings.Settings$AppBatteryUsageActivity"/>
    </Preference>-->

    <Preference
        android:key="special_access"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.applications.specialaccess.SpecialAccessSettings"
        android:title="@string/special_access"
        android:order="20"
        settings:controller="com.android.settings.applications.SpecialAppAccessPreferenceController"/>

</PreferenceScreen>

These is no "Cloud Media app" related layout in it
I want to block "Cloud Media app" in "apps" and "Live Caption" in "Sound & vibration".What do I need to do to.
Thanks!

I've found that in DashboardFragment it is possible to block some of the options that are not present in the xml file, but there are still some options that don't appear here.
